# Undeclared Identifier (header file included)

Tags: c++, qt, slot

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QList<QStringList> csv;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
    QList<QStandardItem*> standardItemList;
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void on_action_Open_triggered();
    void checkString(QString &temp, QChar ch = 0);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**maindwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,SLOT(on_action_Open_triggered()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_action_Open_triggered()
{

    model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open CSV file",QDir::currentPath(), "csv (*.csv)");
    QFile file(fileName);

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {

        QString data = file.readAll();
        data.remove(QRegExp("\r")); // remove all carriage return characters
        QString temp;
        QChar ch;
        QTextStream instream (&data);

        while (!instream.atEnd())
        {
            instream >> ch;
            if (ch == ',')
                checkString(temp, ch);
            else if (ch == '\n')
                checkString(temp, ch);
            else if (instream.atEnd())
            {
                temp.append(ch);
                checkString(temp);
            } else
                temp.append(ch);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::checkString(QString &temp, QChar ch)
{

    if (temp.count("\"")%2 == 0)
    {
        if (temp.startsWith(QChar('\"')) && temp.endsWith(QChar('\"')))
        {
            temp.remove(QRegExp("^\""));
            temp.remove(QRegExp("\"$"));
        }

        temp.replace("\"\"", "\"");
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(temp);
        standardItemList.append(item);

        if (ch != QChar(','))
        {
        }

        temp.clear();
    } else
        temp.append(ch);
}

void something()
{
    qDebug() << standardItemList;
}
```

I am being told standardItemList, undeclared identifier in the something function(why not in the checkstring function?). However I have included mainwindow.h and that includes a definition of standardItemList. does it have something to do with the standardItemList containing *item and that is declared within checkString

Comment: `checkString` is a member function of `class MainWindow`, `something` is not.

Comment: That you very much, it can be a rather big challenge trying to write in C++ after Java as there is so much more to remember and so much to miss

Comment: @user4217633 You wrote Java? You could use [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/), which is made for Java users.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QList<QStringList> csv;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
    QList<QStandardItem*> standardItemList;
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void on_action_Open_triggered();
    void checkString(QString &temp, QChar ch = 0);
    void something();
};

void MainWindow::something()
{
    qDebug() << standardItemList;
}
```

`checkString` is a private member therefore you can't call it from outside the class so `standardItemList` is not defined.